# Prevent receiving all mail: *@mydomain.com in Google Apps, being Super Administrator

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm a Super Administrator for a domain associated with Google Apps. For some reason, I'm receiving *all* mail that is being sent to this domain.

Here's what it says in the Account Settings of my Super Admin's Google Apps mail:

Email addresses:

```
webmaster@mydomain.com  (Primär e-postadress)
*@mydomain.com
```

I'd like to remove ****@mydomain.com*** to prevent receiving everything being sent to @domain.com, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bounce messages addressed to non-existent recipients:

1. Log into the Google Apps control panel for your domain.
2. Click the Settings tab and then select Email in the left column.
3. - (Free edition) In the Catch-all address section, select the Discard radio button.
   - (Other editions) In the Email routing section, select the Discard radio button.

4 .Click Save changes.

[Taken from this Google Help Article](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33962)

Comment: Thanks Barry for your complimentary info. Embarrasingly (but good altogether) I found the answer to the problem in my situation:

In Google Apps, visit the Organization & users settings. Under nicknames, click on Remove *@mydomain.com and everything's in order again.

(Apologies for posting this question/answer. It was perhaps a bit specific to my own quite unique dilemma, although I wasn't aware of that until I found the clue myself.)

Comment: @hced: No problem - glad you have got it sorted now.